# ¿Contexto de una transacción con mongoid?

Tags: mongodb, ruby

Necesito usar transacciones en mongoid para poder ejecutar una serie de operaciones manteniendo la consistencia en caso de fallo.

Según la [documentación oficial](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-transactions/), entiendo que hay que iniciar una sesión sobre un modelo y ejecutar todas las operaciones entre `start_transaction` y `commit_transaction`; pero la parte que no entiendo es el hecho de que se deba iniciar la sesión con un modelo en particular.

No entiendo si es debido a que el modelo dispone de un helper para ello por ser un `Monogid::Document` o si es por el hecho de que las operaciones deben estar relacionadas con el modelo indicado.

¿Alguien sabe la razón?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según [la documentación oficial](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-sessions/), la única forma de trabajar con sesiones en `mongoid` (disponibles en MongoDB a partir de la versión 3.6), es a través de una Clase (Modelo) o de una instancia (modelo). Cosa que tiene todo el sentido cuando se trata de operaciones de tipo transacción que impliquen actualizaciones sobre dicho modelo en particular. Piensa que no tiene sentido iniciar sesión usando el modelo `Post` (por ejemplo) para luego realizar únicamente operaciones sobre el modelo `User`. Es como subir al coche (vehículo) por la puerta del pasajero si lo que harás es conducir el mismo, es más lógico subir por la puerta del conductor.

Ahora bien, durante dicha sesión, aparte de operaciones sobre el modelo donde estableces sesión, puedes también realizar operaciones sobre otro modelo diferente, ya que al fin y al cabo una sesión sólo establece un punto de referencia para la consistencia de las operaciones. Puedes leer al respecto en: [*Client Sessions and Causal Consistency Guarantees*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#std-label-sessions).

En cuanto a tu duda principal:

> No entiendo si es debido a que el modelo dispone de un helper para ello por ser un `Monogid::Document` o si es por el hecho de que las operaciones deben estar relacionadas con el modelo indicado.

Es una combinación de ambas. Ya te expliqué el motivo o lógica detrás del uso de un Modelo particular para iniciar sesión: se hacen operaciones sobre dicho modelo. Y es debido a esta lógica que las instancias y las Clases de `Mongoid::Document` disponen de un `helper` (un método llamado [`with_session`](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-sessions/)) que permite iniciar una sesión usando el cliente por defecto (o algún otro cliente si se especifica).

Pero la sesión no está relacionada con el documento, sino con una propiedad (opción) de la clase `Mongoid::Document` llamada `client`. Recuerda que si no se especifica un cliente particular, se utiliza el cliente por defecto. Puedes configurar tus clientes en el archivo [`mongoid.yml`](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/7.3/tutorials/mongoid-configuration/#mongoid-configuration-options).

Por lo tanto, se inicia sesión sobre un Modelo (Clase) o modelo (instancia) para realizar transacciones (operaciones de lectura/escritura consistentes, aisladas y atómicas) sobre dicho Modelo en particular (o algún otro adicional si así lo requieren las circunstancias) usando el cliente actual de dicho modelo, ya que es dicho modelo el que guarda una referencia o relación sobre el cliente de conexión usado por tu aplicación.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración